# Can anyone help me fix my css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The navigation part of the page has some white space below it..even though I have defined its height as 100%.
I'm trying to achieve full height of the navigation bar, but for some reason I can't get it 
Can you help me fix it?

Here's my code..

https://codepen.io/Ail/pen/LWygrZ

```css
/*navigation*/

nav {
  height: 100%;
}

#navigation {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1em 0em;
  color: white;
  background: #8D0D19;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white
}

ul.sections {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8D0D19;
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #450606;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.active_p {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #450606;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

#navigation li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.pages {
  padding-left: 2em;
  list-style: initial;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #D4E6F4;
  background: #8D0D19;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.section_name {
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.section_name:hover {
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: white
}

.admin_links {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}

.admin_links:hover {
  color: darkslategrey;
}


/*jumbotron*/

.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.msg {
  font-size: 16;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<div class="jumbotron">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <h1>CorpoViz</h1>

  </div>

</div>

<nav id=navigation>
  <ul class="sections">

    <!--COMMENT passed a query string below to identify the section-->
    <li>
      <!-- below code highlights the current section -->
      <a class="section_name" href="?section=1">
                 About</a>


      <ul class=pages>


      </ul>

    </li>
    <!--COMMENT passed a query string below to identify the section-->
    <li>
      <!-- below code highlights the current section -->
      <a class="section_name" href="?section=2">
                 Projects</a>


      <ul class=pages>


        <li>
          <!-- below code highlights the current page -->
          <a href="manage_content.php?page=1">
                        Project 1</a>
        </li>


        <li>
          <!-- below code highlights the current page -->
          <a href="manage_content.php?page=2">
                        Project 2</a>
        </li>


      </ul>

    </li>
    <!--COMMENT passed a query string below to identify the section-->
    <li>
      <!-- below code highlights the current section -->
      <a class="section_name" href="?section=3">
                 Products</a>


      <ul class=pages>


        <li>
          <!-- below code highlights the current page -->
          <a href="manage_content.php?page=3">
                        Product 1</a>
        </li>


        <li>
          <!-- below code highlights the current page -->
          <a href="manage_content.php?page=4">
                        Product 2</a>
        </li>


      </ul>

    </li>
    <!--COMMENT passed a query string below to identify the section-->
    <li>
      <!-- below code highlights the current section -->
      <a class="section_name" href="?section=4">
                 Others</a>


      <ul class=pages>


      </ul>

    </li>


  </ul>


</nav>
<div class="container-fluid" id=main>


  <div class="container" id=page style="padding:30px;">

    <h2>Create new Section</h2><br>

    <form action=create_section.php method=post>

      <div class="form-group">

        <label style="font-size:18px" for="section_name">Section name </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="section_name" name="section_name" style="width:60%">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

        <label style="font-size:18px" for="position">Position </label>
        <select class="form-control" id="position" style="width:60%" name=position>
                    <option value=1>1</option><option value=2>2</option><option value=3>3</option><option value=4>4</option><option value=5>5</option>                </select>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

        <label style="font-size:18px">Status </label><br>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type=radio name=status class="s_visible"  value="1">Visible</label>&nbsp;
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type=radio name=status class="s_hidden"  value="0">Hidden</label>

      </div>
      <br>
      <input type=submit name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create Section"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

      <a href="manage_content.php" class="btn btn-danger">&#10006; Cancel</a>

    </form>



  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are missing some of your HTML code on here.

Comment: I created you a snippet and commented out the unnecessary JS which is not allowed to run in a sandbox anyway. Also you had TWO jQueries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom whitespace is coming not from your nav, but from the `.container`, which has 30px of padding on all sides (including the bottom). If you want to keep that padding on the other sides, you can just change the style on that `.container` to `padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;`

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWmQXz)

Note: if you also wanted to remove the whitespace *on top* of the navbar, that could be done by setting the following:

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Using `!important` should generally be avoided, but would be needed here because you can't edit the Bootstrap LESS. So, my final recommendation (and what's currently in the pen), would be to add a new class to the jumbotron element (let's call it `.tight`), which will allow you to have a specific enough declaration without `!important`, like so:

```
.jumbotron.tight {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: There is still space at the top of the navigation though ?

Comment: But the problem still seems to persist as I'm adding more elements to my nav bar

Comment: Let me know if my updates helped explain a bit better; I just tried adding some elements to the nav in a new pen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqdQMp), and the spacing seems to be remaining correct.

Comment: Your updates seems to work fine in the pen for me , but it's not helping me on my web browser (Chrome). Here is the new pen http://codepen.io/Ail/pen/EWmOrw

Comment: Hmmm... your pen seems to be working fine for me as well ([screenshot 1](http://imgur.com/DHXkVoD), [screenshot 2](http://imgur.com/WryUFRK)). If you're seeing any issues on your browser, would you mind posting a screenshot pointing out the problem?

Comment: Got it - I tried it out by using the source files on my own browser, and was able to replicate the issue. Thanks. I've [updated the pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJdNMq) one more time, with the fixes that worked on Chrome for me (screenshot [here](http://imgur.com/qJW18eb)). Basically, two instances of `margin-bottom`, and since margin is not accounted for in calculating widths & heights, the surrounding elements end up higher than the end of the page. Check out lines 32 & 57 of the CSS in the pen.

Comment: Finally...got my desired output..Thank you so much @JackKoppa for putting your valuable time into this..Cheers

Comment: Happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

Follow tips of @jack and add this code in your css:

```
.jumbotron {    
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Another .jumbotron already has the "margin-bottom". it will force to set the margin-bottom to 0!

Answer (score 0):

To remove white space from top of the navigation,

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

To achieve full height of the navigation bar

```
#navigation {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em 0em;
    color: white;
    background: #8D0D19;
    height: 100%;
    /* float: left; */
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 249px;
}

#main{
        margin: 0 0 0 200px;
}
```

Change "container" class to "col-sm-12" from the bellow :

```
<div class="container" id=page style="padding:30px;">
```

Comment: This aint't helping.